# sklearn LassoLars solution not least squares when alpha=0

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the numerical instability in the code that causes the solution to deviate from least squares when the penalty coefficient alpha=0.  The issue is mentioned in passing in the documentation but not where it fails.  I have an example that fails to give the least squares solution on only one out of five components.  I'm having trouble finding the source of the bad behavior in the code.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

y= np.array([ -6.45006793,  -3.51251449,  -8.52445396,   6.12277822, -19.42109366])
x=np.array([[ 0.47299829,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.08239882,  0.85784863,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.30114139, -0.07501577,  0.80895216,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [-0.01460346, -0.1015233 ,  0.0407278 ,  0.80338378,  0.        ],
   [-0.69363927,  0.06754067,  0.18064514, -0.0803561 ,  0.40427291]])
test=linear_model.LassoLars(0, fit_intercept=False)
test.fit(x.T, y)
test_compare=linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
test_compare.fit(x.T, y)

test.coef_- test_compare.coef_
```

The output for the difference in coefficients (test.coef_- test_compare.coef_) is:

```
array([  4.26325641e-14,  -5.96744876e-15,  -3.57739709e+00,
     1.37667655e-14,   2.84217094e-14])
```

Thanks!  I'm a bit of newbie, so helpful comments on how I can improve the question are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the code!

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7778
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7849#issuecomment-259796642